# Java Authentication through Server

Tags: java, php

So I have a Java Application and want Users which i created to be able to log in and change their Password, I've read a few things about the Topic but i can't seem to figure out how to do it properly.

So in my Application I need to make an HTTP request to my Server, got a database with the username, hashed password and the access privileges, this is as much as I found. So my question is if this would work

The Second question would be, do i just make a php script running on apache that checks the Database or do i need to do some more for it to work?

```
    String hostname = "url";

    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    provider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(new HttpHost(hostname)), credentials);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

    String query = "url";

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(query);
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }
        finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Comment: note that you probably want to use hashing on the server-side.

Comment: by that you mean, sending the password to the server in hashed form, right?

Comment: So you have a Java application that interacts with a web server that runs PHP? If so, you should pick a winner for this. One way is that Java does all the logic and PHP is just the transport to the database. The other way is that PHP is also an application, and it controls some of the logic, including hashing, and you create an API for Java to interact with PHP.

Comment: @Matze._ No, the client/server communication is encrypted, not hashed. The server then hashes the password (with a salt) and compares the hashes.

Comment: Regarding @ChrisHaas's comment: In many cases (especially authentication/authorisation), trusting clients (picking the client as the "winner") is a bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisHaas So if i choose Java as the logic controller, i just need a php script that returns a basic "okay" if the credentials match, that's what you're saying, so in conclusion java sends a get, php connects to database checks username and hashed password and sends "okay"

Comment: @dan1st So, what do you exactly mean by picking PHP as the logic controller, the only thing the server can do is say credentials correct or not, no?

Comment: Depends - there is probably a reason (in your application) why you need a login. For that, you might need additional sercer capabilities. For example, if your server would store private data, the server should only allow access to that data from authenticated users that actually do have access to that data. The server would need to validate that because the user is essentially in control over the app.

Comment: I would recommend to always transport sensitive information in a POST instead of a GET, it avoids some accidental logging. To @dan1st, yes, I agree, the Java client can be decompiled, and although there’s mitigations, it would require logic server-side anyway. So this really should be in PHP. When someone is “logged in”, in order to stay “logged in” the server sends a response, generally a cookie but could be something else. Instead of just “ok”, return a unique token that clients can present to the server to perform requests that need authentication, such as password reset.

Comment: One question, wouldn't it technicly be the safest and fastest way to directly contact the database, so java sends credentials to database, then the database (in my case mssql) answers directly if the user has access or not.

Comment: You might be asking this the wrong way around. What kind of application do you have and what do you need the credentials / permissions in your application for?

Comment: Well, I need them to know which Databases belong to the User / which are associated with them, so i could just run through a list of all the Databases and check which one they have access to, right?

Comment: I’m assuming your Java client is a mobile device (phone, tablet, etc.). If so, that device’s file system can be accessed raw and the source code decompiled giving an attacker direct access to the database. If you are lucky, you catch them, but then you need to change the credentials for all clients which means they are all broken until update. If you do this server-side, you _might_ get pounded with HTTP requests, but there are mitigations and services for this at least.